# What is the count of subarrays that will include a particular index 'i'?

Tags: arrays, combinations, permutation, combinatorics, sub-array

Consider an array of 'n' elements, where a*i* is an element at index *i* where 1<=i<=N.
I need to count the number of sub-arrays(contiguous sub-sequences of the array) that will include a particular index *i*.
For example, consider,
A = [1,2,3,4,5]
The element 2 at index *2*, will be included in 8 sub-arrays- {2},{1,2},{2,3},{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}.

Is there a way to frame a formula for this in terms of array size *n* and selected index *i*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of sequences including index `i` is going to be equal to the number of sequences to the left of `i` times the number to the right. For both left and right we have to include the empty sequence.

In your example these would be:

```
left: {}, {1}
right: {}, {3}, {3,4}, {3,4,5}
```

Pairing each left sequence with every right sequence, with `i` in the center obviously, gives you the 8 sub-arrays in your example. (If you consider left and right above as sets then you're looking to form the [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)).

The number of left sequences is just `i`, the number on the right is `n-i+1`. The total is therefore `i*(n-i+1)`.